# JMeter - I am saving the test results in a CSV but it does not show any Response Data. Does the Response Data only work for XML?

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I get a JSON Response from my API. The results save configuration window only shows XML, and the csv generated does not have any response data.
[image]

Does this not work with JSON responses?

Generated the CSV, got these columns only:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) to XML mode and see response data in there you need to amend JMeter [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) and add at least the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
```

see other properties and enable saving of those you're interested in. However be aware that it [violates JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) because it causes massive disk IO and can impact or even ruin your test.

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)